# Query to identify gaps in time data

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm pretty new to database programming, and I'm in need some help writing what seems to be a complicated t-sql query.

Our database stores time data along with various levels recorded at that time.  A typical measurement will last for weeks or months.  I need to write a query in SqlServer2005 to identify gaps in the time data to know when the instrument wasn't communicating.  Our sample interval can be either 1 sec or .5 sec, but it will always be the same in a given measurement (ie: all samples in a measurement will be either 1 or .5 samples/sec).

Ideally I would like to get a list of 
[block1-start block1-end]
[block2-start block2-end]
etc

where each block is a unit of consecutive times within the overall measurement.

Are there any commands in TSQL that would make this query easier?

Comment: Can measurements overlap in time?

Comment: See [this article on Simple Talk](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/find-missing-date-ranges-in-sql/)

Comment: No, there will be no overlap in times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this out.  Since you don't have overlapping intervals you can write a simple SQL query to return these results.  The SQL below creates a dummy table variable called @Events to simulate your measurements table.  The final query outputs the gaps greater than 1 second (configurable via variable @MaxIntervalAllowedBetweenEvents).

```
-- table with dummy data
declare @Events table (
    ID          int IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    StartDate   datetime NOT NULL,
    EndDate     datetime NOT NULL
)
INSERT @Events VALUES ('1/1/2011 1:00am', '1/1/2011 2:00am')
INSERT @Events VALUES ('1/1/2011 2:00am', '1/1/2011 3:00am')  -- no gap after previous event
INSERT @Events VALUES ('1/1/2011 3:01am', '1/1/2011 4:00am')  -- 1 minute gap
INSERT @Events VALUES ('1/1/2011 4:30am', '1/1/2011 5:00am')  -- 30 minute gap


-- this variable defines the maximum interval allowed between events
declare @MaxIntervalAllowedBetweenEvents int
set @MaxIntervalAllowedBetweenEvents = 1    -- # seconds


-- select the gaps between events
SELECT
    e1.EndDate,
    Min(e2.StartDate) as NextEventStartDate,
    DateDiff(s, e1.EndDate, Min(e2.StartDate)) as SecondsBetweenEvents
FROM
    @Events as e1
join
    -- for each event in e1, get the event that immediately follows it
    @Events as e2
        on  (e1.EndDate <= e2.StartDate)
GROUP BY
    e1.EndDate
HAVING
    -- filter out events that are too close to each other
    (DateDiff(s, e1.EndDate, Min(e2.StartDate)) > @MaxIntervalAllowedBetweenEvents)
ORDER BY
    e1.EndDate
```

Comment: pretty nice solution.  I thought you would have needed a procedure for this.  But it looks like you can easily do this is sql too.

Comment: Thanks!  Now if the dates could overlap then it would be really complex.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has a lot of great analytical functions for this.

I think would you need to do is create a cursor from a sql statement that will order you results by Date, StartTime,EndTime.

Answer (score 1):

A table that takes a Date input can be used like this to get the time between logins...

Omit the ROW_NUMBER bit if your table already has an Identity on it.

```
{select 
    Start.ID
    ,Done.ID
    ,Start.<Date_Column>
    ,Done.<Date_Column>
    ,DATEDIFF(s,Start.<Date_Column>,Done.<Date_Column>) AS InBetween
from 
    (SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY <Date_Column>) AS ID
        ,<Date_Column>
    FROM
        <Tablename> (NOLOCK)
    ) START
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY <Date_Column>) AS ID
            ,<Date_Column>
        FROM
            <Tablename> (NOLOCK)
        ) DONE  ON START.ID + 1 = DONE.ID
ORDER BY
    DATEDIFF(s,Start.<Date_Column>,Done.<Date_Column>)DESC}
```